# want to return Value json on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I want to ask about how to return json and the result is only VALUE.

I have code in my controller like this:

```
$firstName = User::select('user_first_name')->get();

$firstNameArray = array();

foreach ($firstName as $firstNames) {
    $firstNameArray[] = $firstNames->$firstName;
}


return response()->json($firstNameArray);
```

The current result is:

```
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
```

When i check my database, there are my data. and when i code like this

```
$firstName = User::select('user_first_name')->get();

return response()->json($firstName);
```

This will show the following result:

```
[
    {"user_first_name":"Jillian"},
    {"user_first_name":"Kayden"},
    {"user_first_name":"Alize"},
    {"user_first_name":"Kelli"},
    {"user_first_name":"Loyce"},
    {"user_first_name":"Jarrell"},
    {"user_first_name":"Vivianne"},
    {"user_first_name":"Annalise"},
    {"user_first_name":"Rosalee"},
    {"user_first_name":"Jerrod"},
    {"user_first_name":"Yvette"},
    {"user_first_name":"Libby"},
    {"user_first_name":"Lorenz"},
    {"user_first_name":"Alisha"},
    {"user_first_name":"Jerrold"},
    {"user_first_name":"Amya"},
    {"user_first_name":"Columbus"},
    {"user_first_name":"Gwen"},
    {"user_first_name":"Kaylie"},
    {"user_first_name":"Lafayette"}
]
```

My question is, how can I show the name as an ARRAY without showing NULL.

Comment: To many dollars chnage to `$firstNames->firstName`

Comment: still same here

Answer (score 2):

Remove the $ sign from statement in the `foreach` loop and use `user_first_name` instead of `firstName`:

```
foreach ($firstName as $firstNames) {
    $firstNameArray[] = $firstNames->user_first_name;
}
```

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's, we make a quick comment and then close the question as TYPO's are almost never any use to others

Comment: Correct, but an answer is easy to read. And yes this also will close the ticket.

Comment: already tried it. but still null

Comment: It means that the structure of  `$firstNames` may be slightly different. Try `print_r($firstNames);` and put the proper variable structure to pull the values.

Comment: Thank you !! already solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$firstNameArray = User::select('user_first_name')->pluck('user_first_name');
return response()->json($firstNameArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$firstname = User::select('user_first_name')->get();

return $firstname;
```

Output will be:

```
[
    { "user_first_name": "test name" },
    { "user_first_name": "test name" }
]
```

Comment: ya. but i want the format as an ARRAY not as an Object

Comment: my output is 
[{"c_name":"test name"},{"c_name":"test name1"}]